# In Java Swing how can you manage a list of panels allowing multiple panels to be selected?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

I’m working on an in-house app that tracks a bunch of tasks. I wanted to have a simple task monitor that would list the task name and the task’s status. I need this to look just a little nice, I’m no designer so whatever I do is going to suck, but a basic text display won’t work for the project requirements.

What I am essentially attempting to do is show something similar to the Firefox download window, the I-Tunes download window, and well I could name more but they all look basically the same. In each of these apps, each of the ‘progress panels’ is selectable. So to implement this I thought it would be simple to just use a list of JPanels each with a JProgressBar and a JLabel, each of which can just accept focus to determine if it and others are selected. I thought this was going to be an easy task, but if I use a JList it just displays text. I then just figured I would show all the task panels in a larger panel, but I cannot get the inner panels to recognize focus.

Is there a pattern for this? Is there a rolled standard solution that I just have not found? Or is there a better method for doing this? I don’t want to re-invent the wheel, but I thought this was just going to be simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like what you may be looking for is an [`JList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

You can add your items to the `JList`'s by first adding your "task" to the `JList` object's [`ListModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) (see the [Create a Model](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) section from The Java Tutorials), and then you'll want to assigned a custom [`ListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) which will accept your "task" and render on the `JList` as a `JPanel` in the list itself. The key here is to make your custom `ListCellRenderer` be able to display your "task" in the `JList` the way you want to have it show on the `JList`.

Take a look into the [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) section from the [How to Use Lists](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) page of The Java Tutorials. It will describe how to make your custom `ListCellRenderer` so you can represent your "task" as anything you want.

To keep it short, you will implement the [`ListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) interface by implementing the [`getListCellRendererComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JList,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)) which will return a [`Component`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) which is the representation of your task in the `JList`. You'll probably want to either construct or instantiate your `JPanel` in this method and return it as the `Component`.

Comment: Here's some simple code showing how to render JPanels in a JList as alluded to in the answer: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0203.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this kind of things is to use JTable (or JList) as a container.

You don't have to use default renderes fot table cells, but you can specify your own renderer for specific cells. Take a look at [CellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about a `JTable` (which you can set to allow multiple rows to be selected) with an internal `JPanel` occupying the single cell in each row, which contains a `JProgressBar` and a `JLabel`. Or you could use a `JList` with the same structure as I just described.